# In for in loop, how is the name defined for each array item in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

How is the name "fruit" defined.

```
let fruits = ["Apples", "Peaches", "Plums"]

for fruit in fruits {
    print("I have \(fruit).")
}
```

also this works, where "fruit" has been changed to "item"

```
let fruits = ["Apples", "Peaches", "Plums"]

for item in fruits {
    print("I have \(item).")
}
```

but on some other array "for in" loops I've had errors that read "Immutable value 'minutes' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it"

...where "minutes" is supposed to represent individual items in an array of Ints.  Why would I get this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is the name "fruit" defined

*You* defined it by saying `for fruit`. You defined it as a local variable inside the curly braces only.

> I've had errors that read "Immutable value 'minutes' was never used

It's a warning, not an error. If you take out the `print` statement, you will get that warning. This happens because you defined a variable `fruit` when you said `for fruit` but then you never *used* it in the curly braces - thus making the compiler complain about a variable that was declared but never used.

Comment: Aaaah this made sense...now I get it, thank you for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```
let fruits = ["Apples", "Peaches", "Plums"]
for minutes in fruits {
}
```

If you are using this kind of scenario then it shows a warning "Immutable value 'minutes' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it". Because you are not using minutes anywhere in the code